# single word or phrase for particular feeling of release

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, idioms

Is there a word that describes when you have a great idea, revolutionary even, and then you find out it has already been done?  Or maybe, that feeling - not futility, not Sisyphean - but that wry release of pent up motivation to act, upon finding out, there's nothing left to do.

Comment: You mean like "Aw, shit!"?

Comment: Would _deflation_ work?

Answer (score 7):

[Deflated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deflate):

> feeling less ​confident and ​positive than before; to reduce in size, importance, or effectiveness (Cambridge dictionary/MW)

An example of its usage:

> But on that August afternoon when we finally landed at Narita and took our bearings, we felt deflated. The place looked depressingly ordinary. - NYT